# WordPress Updates 3.5.2 to 3.8 Any Problem?

Tags: updates

I have a question which is so easy but if it's wrong then I'll lose everything. I have a site which is working on WordPress 3.5.2 and now I got the 3.8 version. I want to update it, which is easy, but the problem is, I don't have backup functionality.

So is this safe to just click the update link or will I face any problem and lose all my data?

Please advise what should I do? Should I take the risk to click & update my WordPress or ignore it?

Comment: I would suggest upgrading incrementally to avoid potential conflicts and minimise the risks of database damage. See instructions here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_-_Extended_Instructions

Answer (score 0):

You should back-up your database and files if you are in any doubt whatsoever. It isn't particularly hard to do.

See this article on Backing Up WordPress, taken from the Codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups

Answer (score 0):

The last time Wordpress changed their database structure was in Version 3.0. So, there shouldn't be any problem migrating.

But you should always backup to be safe as `@henrywright` said.

From the Wordpress Codex:

**Back up your database regularly, and always before an upgrade.**